# covariate-adjusted analysis for time to event endpoint in a cross over design RCT

Tags: cox-model, mixed-model, crossover-study, recurrent-events

I have a time to event endpoint in a 2x2 crossover RCT which I would like to analyse with a regression model to adjust for covariate effects. I am supposing I cannot fit a Cox proportional Hazards model due to the double-censoring that can occur on the same subject?

Instead I am wondering if the Anderson-Gill model for repeatable events might be suitable? Even if I can do this, the resulting analysis presumably would not take advantage of the paired nature of the data? By this I mean I expect (due to not much missing data) that most of the information on the treatment effect can be obtained by comparing within subjects - this is exactly what happens when using a linear mixed model for normally distributed endpoints (although I am not sure how the REML estimator automatically pulls this trick off!).

Another option which takes advantage of the paired data but does not estimate covariate effects would be to analyse the binary versions of the time to event endpoint with a McNemar test.

Does anybody have any experience, or thoughts on this subject?